# Deseo imprimir el resultado de un input en python

Tags: python

quisiera poder imprimir la variable o un elemento de una lista especifica de un mes, al hacer un input del 1 al 6 quisiera que coincida y lo imprima, si pongo input=1 que imprima "enero"

```
mes1="enero"
mes2="febrero"
mes3="marzo"
mes4="abril"
mes5="mayo"
mes6="junio"

meses=["enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio"]

num1  = int(input("ingrese un numero del 1 al 6 para indicarle el mes: "))

print(num1.meses[])
```

Answer (score 2):

Veo que utilizaste dos veces lo mismo (primero variables, luego la lista) para hablar de lo mismo. Te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

```
meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio"]
num1  = int(input("ingrese un numero del 1 al 6 para indicarle el mes: "))

print("Elegiste el numero", num1, "es el mes", meses[num1 - 1])
```

En el siguiente código le pedimos al usuario a través del input que elija un número y según cual sea lanza el mes. *Pongo meses[num1 - 1] para que puedas arrancar mes1 = Enero, de lo contrario al digitar el "1" saldría Febrero.*
No está de mas aclarar que si el usuario agrega un numero menor que 1 o mayor que 6 el codigo no funciona, ya que no hay meses siguientes.

Comment: Excelente me quedo muy bien muchas gracias y pensando hacer varios switch :D

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto a tu inquietud podrías acceder a la lista utilizando el index, aunque debes de tener en cuenta el "off-by-one", lo que significa que si intentas acceder a el mes de enero tendrás que colocar el index de num1 = 1 + 1(para evitar el off-by-one). Aquí te dejo un ejemplo del código.

```
meses=["enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio"]

num1  = int(input("ingrese un numero del 1 al 6 para indicarle el mes: "))

print(meses[num1 + 1])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :D